# how can I access to a specific element in json

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I have a JSON from telegram, In php How can find that if it is a text do something, but if its photo, audio or ... do something else. this part is located after date, how can I access it?

I tried by access it by index like `['message'][1]` but I got error.

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "update_id": 30213598,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 41,
        "from": {
          "id": 102768333,
          "first_name": "QWr_1",
          "username": "john"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 108768733,
          "first_name": "QWr_1",
          "username": "john"
        },
        "date": 1439233778,
        "text": "this is a test"
      }
    },
        {
      "update_id": 30213599,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 46,
        "from": {
          "id": 108768733,
          "first_name": "QWr_1",
          "username": "john"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 108768733,
          "first_name": "QWr_1",
          "username": "john"
        },
        "date": 1439234126,
        "photo": [
          {
            "file_id": "AgADBAAD4acxG92tewa8uRLrpBBo-h1icjAABCohC6S9uPdhViIAAgI",
            "file_size": 1923,
            "width": 90,
            "height": 90
          },
          {
            "file_id": "AgADBAAD4acxG92tewa8uRLrpBBo-h1icjAABOT4Q5CJoFOVVSIAAgI",
            "file_size": 24105,
            "width": 320,
            "height": 320
          },
          {
            "file_id": "AgADBAAD4acxG92tewa8uRLrpBBo-h1icjAABK2WgDnJ74jlVCIAAgI",
            "file_size": 57650,
            "width": 640,
            "height": 640
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `json_decode` function.

I use `foreach` loop then `echo $item['message']['message_id']` to display `message_id` in following example.

Try Example

```
$json = <<<JSON
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "update_id": 30213598,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 41,
        "from": {
          "id": 102768333,
          "first_name": "QWr_1",
          "username": "john"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 108768733,
          "first_name": "QWr_1",
          "username": "john"
        },
        "date": 1439233778,
        "text": "this is a test"
      }
    },
        {
      "update_id": 30213599,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 46,
        "from": {
          "id": 108768733,
          "first_name": "QWr_1",
          "username": "john"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 108768733,
          "first_name": "QWr_1",
          "username": "john"
        },
        "date": 1439234126,
        "photo": [
          {
            "file_id": "AgADBAAD4acxG92tewa8uRLrpBBo-h1icjAABCohC6S9uPdhViIAAgI",
            "file_size": 1923,
            "width": 90,
            "height": 90
          },
          {
            "file_id": "AgADBAAD4acxG92tewa8uRLrpBBo-h1icjAABOT4Q5CJoFOVVSIAAgI",
            "file_size": 24105,
            "width": 320,
            "height": 320
          },
          {
            "file_id": "AgADBAAD4acxG92tewa8uRLrpBBo-h1icjAABK2WgDnJ74jlVCIAAgI",
            "file_size": 57650,
            "width": 640,
            "height": 640
          }
        ]
      }
    }
]
}
JSON;

$json_data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($json_data['result'] as $item)
{
    if(isset($item['message']['text']))
    {
        echo $item['message']['text']."<br />";
    }

    if(isset($item['message']['photo']))
    {
        foreach($item['message']['photo'] as $photo)
        {
            echo "file_id: ".$photo['file_id']."<br />";
            echo "file_size: ".$photo['file_size']."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to fetch, but I need to find out this is a text message or photo, document...

Comment: @Mohammad I have updated my answer. Use `echo $item['message']['text']` to display text message.

Comment: Thank you, as you can see in second loop it causes an error because instead of 'text', its 'photo' , I need a code to check if its a text or photo, so if find that what it is, If its text I return the text, but if it is a photo I return file_id, file_size ....

Comment: @Mohammad Please accept my answer. If you found it useful.

Comment: YES! Thaks alot, thats the key.

Comment: @Mohammad I'm glad it works for you. Please vote up my answer.